# How can I automatically update a given document on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have an old PC that I use only to run numerical simulations, while doing most of the work on my laptop. Being often out, I can't always have easy physical access to the former, with the obvious pain of having to wait till I get home to know the outputs of my works. Moreover, every time I have to open Google Drive and update the *.dat* files produced by the simulation in order to work with them on the laptop.

**Hence my question**: Is there any Google Drive' set up which every *n* hours can update a given document to the cloud?

I tried searching both the Internet and this site, but came to nothing; if it's a duplicate, tell me and I'll shut the question down upon display of proper references.

Also, since I'm new to this Web Applications Stack Exchange, I would greatly appreciate if you could help me with the inclusion of proper tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this easily with the native application of Google Drive called **Backup and Sync** - **https://www.google.com/drive/download/**

- download it
- install it
- in settings include the folder in which you output **`.dat`** files into Drive sync folder or output them directly in Drive sync folder if it's possible

Comment: It worked, thanks! Just one more question; can I choose how often backup the selected directories?

Comment: not directly in the settings of Backup&Sync but yes, it's possible to schedule it with some 3rd-party app or natively in OS via scheduler or batch scripts (to launch the Backup&Sync at given times).